# Temporarily get jest coverage to show only files in a specific folder

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage

For my reactjs app, I'm adding integration tests to a view and want to keep an eye on coverage along the way.  I'm currently getting all files on every run.

### Question

While adding tests to increase coverage, how can I get jest coverage to show only files in a specific folder?

### Examples tried

- $ `yarn test --collectCoverageFrom=src/app/components/Tools`
  Test run, bu no coverage is showing here.
- $ `yarn test Tools --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/app/components/Tools`
  I get `Ran all test suites matching "Tools".`
- $ `yarn test src/app/components/Tools --coverage`
  Here I see the coverage percentage is smaller but still lists all files.
- $ `yarn test -o --coverage`
  Again as the previous, I see the coverage percentage is smaller but still lists all files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be best to have an argument in the CLI, but you can add a temporary script in your `package.json`:

`"tools-coverage": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom src/app/components/Tools --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/app/components/Tools/**/*.js"`

Running the full command in the terminal just doesn't work.

Now you can instead run $ `yarn tools-coverage` to just test your Tools folder you targeted in your package.json.

An example shown here in the `create-react-app` issue:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1455#issuecomment-277010725

Comment: How to get coverage for only changed files? If not possible, how to get coverage for a defined list of files?

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera have you found the solution?